# Flutter web client at Windows 7, app runs in browser but buttons frozen

Tags: flutter, windows-7, flutter-web

I have an issue with the web app client running in the browser on Windows 7. Unfortunately, some clients still use Windows 7. The app runs on the browser, but all buttons are disabled. It is the same issue with Chrome and Firefox which are updated. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks for any help!